# Can an element's class change depending on whether browser is widened or narrowed?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, responsive, breakpoints

I want to set a class to an element during width-change, depending on whether the browser-width is widened or narrowed. If narrowed, the element receives the first class; if widened, the second.

<--- class=“narrow”     |       ---> class=“widen”

If it can be done, my first choice is CSS, else, JavaScript (or a combo of the two). I have no idea how to approach the issue, I only know that CSS media queries is not giving me what I want.

Comment: `@media` for CSS could help

Comment: Technically, the window size is recalculated only at the time of painting it. So it's never really "shrinking" or "growing", it's always just "in a given state". If you stop resizing your window right before the last calculation occurs, the state won't change anymore. So having such a "moving state" is not really possible to define. You can of course define yours, in JS by determining what is a reasonable amount of time after the last event to decide it's not moving anymore, and thus determine that during this interval it's either growing, shrinking, or stalling.

Comment: Thanks, Kaiido, I thought as much. I just hoped someone knew something I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media. Check the size of screen, set 2 @media rules. In each rule, you can change CSS properties of the same class.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not working. The @media is not aware if the window is being narrowed or widened; it only responds if the width is within the specified rage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript **matchMedia** method as follow:

```js
function changeClass(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("narrow");
        document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove("widen");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove("narrow");
        document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("widen");
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 400px)")
changeClass(x) // Call listener function at run time

x.addEventListener("change", () => {
    changeClass(x);
});
```

```css
.narrow {
    color: red;
}

.widen {
    color: rgb(45, 230, 45);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="myDiv">
        this is the div
    </div>
    
    <script src="myCode.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If the browser width is greater than **700px** it changes the class to **.widen** and if it is less than **700px** it changes the class to **.narrow**.

Comment: Your example works fine for 2 breakpoints, but it does not if there are 3 or more. Consider 3 widths: x-small: 0 - 300px —— small: 301px - 600px —— medium: 601px - 900px. 

I want a different class applied to the element when resizing from 900px down to 400px, than when resizing from 100px up to 400px. I hope my ability to describe this concept is adequate.

Comment: @metaplast I edited the code in a way that between ```400px to 900px``` it gives the ```.narrow``` class and before and after that it gives ```.widen``` class. But I suggest to read the examples from [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to understand better that which condition you could set in **matchMedia** method.

Comment: I probably didn’t explain this as eloquently as I could have. I don’t want just to set an element to .narrow between 400px to 900px. I can already do that with @media rules. 

Rather, when the browser width reaches anywhere between `400px to 900px`, **after the page was sized-up** (i.e. widened), the `div` gets `class=“widen”`. But, **if the page is shrunk-down** (i.e. narrowed) to that **same width** (400px - 900px), the **same** `div` gets `class=“narrow”` instead  (caps used for clarity).

As @Kaiido explained, what I want is not possible, which sounds reasonable to me.